# How do I send a pdf saved with python in an email?

Tags: python, selenium, email

I'm trying to get my pdf to be sent to the client's email. When I use a code to do this, I get this error: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'" Why does it say is NoneType to begin with? How do I make the code better?

This is the code with the pdf:

```
#save screenshot 
sleep(4)
constancia =  wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/table[2]')))
constancia_screenshot = constancia.screenshot_as_png
               
a = io.BytesIO(constancia_screenshot)

image1 = Image.open(a)
im1 = image1.convert('RGB')
pdf = im1.save(r'constancia.pdf')
                   
#send pdf through email
               
constancia_email(pdf, email)
```

This is the code with the email:

```
import smtplib 
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart 
from email.mime.text import MIMEText 
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase 
from email import encoders 

def constancia_email(pdf, email):
   fromaddr = ""
   toaddr = email

   # MIMEMultipart 
   msg = MIMEMultipart() 
 
   msg['From'] = fromaddr 
   msg['To'] = toaddr 
   msg['Subject'] = "Constancia Monotributo"
   body = "Constancia Monotributo Descargada"
       
   
   msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain')) 
       
   # open the file to be sent  
   filename = "Constancia_Monotributo.pdf"
   attachment = pdf
       
   # instance of MIMEBase and named as p 
   p = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream') 
       
   # To change the payload into encoded form 
   p.set_payload(attachment.read()) 
       
   # encode into base64 
   encoders.encode_base64(p) 
   p.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename) 
       
   # attach the instance 'p' to instance 'msg' 
   msg.attach(p) 
       
   # creates SMTP session 
   s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) 
       
   # start TLS for security 
   s.starttls() 
       
   # Authentication 
   s.login(fromaddr, "Password_of_the_sender") 
       
   # Converts the Multipart msg into a string 
   text = msg.as_string() 
       
   # sending the mail 
   s.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text) 
       
   # terminating the session 
   s.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`im1.save` does not return anything.  You'll have to read the contents.

```
im1.save('constancia.pdf')
pdf = open('constancia.pdf','rb').read()
```